# How to move a specific trunk revision and its subsequent edits to a branch?

Tags: svn, branch

We realized that we would like some work in the trunk to have actually have been in a branch.  We would like several commits to go into a branch, and preferably, we would preserve the history of the commits.  So:

```
r0 --- r1 --- r2 --- r3
```

would become

```
          branch --- r2 --- r3
         /
r0 --- r1 ----- *
```

Where "*" is where we will start making new commits to the trunk.  I'm nervous that I'll destroy our repository if I do something incorrectly.  Please advise, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the current status of trunk is good for the branch, so you should just do a server-side `svn copy` from `trunk` to the desired `branches` subdirectory:

```
svn copy svn://path/to/trunk svn://path/to/branches/foo -m "Creating branch Foo"
```

Then you would need to revert trunk to r1, which is easily achieved by either applying a reverse patch from r1 to r3 or by actually using svn merge:

```
svn merge r3:r1 svn://path/to/trunk
```

EDIT: Actually, there's a better solution here: [How do I properly branch post-commit and revert the trunk in svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148902/how-do-i-properly-branch-post-commit-and-revert-the-trunk-in-svn)